# Two dictionaries nested inside a list returns an ValueError - How to

Tags: python, dictionary, valueerror

I nested the two dictionaries `data_dict_var_1` and `data_dict_var_2` inside the list `data_dicts`.

The two dictionaries both include three keys `interoception` `exteroception` and `cognitive`. Each key contains an array of numeric values, such as `{'interoception': array([-1.10037122, -1.12865588, -0.70395085,... ]`.

My aim is as follows:
I would like to take the arrays of the three keys and merge them together into one list. This is achieved by the following part of the code:

```
all_rois = np.array([
        data_dict["interoception"],
        data_dict["exteroception"],
        data_dict["cognitive"]
        ])
    all_rois = np.hstack(all_rois)
```

Using a for loop, I would like to merge the three keys’ arrays for the two dictionaries  instead of repeating the code individually for each dictionary.

Furthermore, I would like to append the merged arrays of `data_dict_var_1` to `var_1_list = []`, while the merged arrays of `data_dict_var_2` have to be appended to `var_2_list = []`.

Here is the full code that makes the problem described below easier to understand:

```
var_1_list = []
var_2_list = []

data_dicts = [data_dict_var_1, data_dict_var_2]
for data_dict in data_dicts:
    all_rois = np.array([
        data_dict["interoception"],
        data_dict["exteroception"],
        data_dict["cognitive"]
        ])
    all_rois = np.hstack(all_rois)
    
    if data_dict == data_dict_var_1:
        var_1_list.append(all_rois)
    elif data_dict == data_dict_var_2:
        var_2_list.append(all_rois)
```

**The problem is as follows:** Python returns `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` for the following if line of the code: `if data_dict == data_dict_var_1:`.

How can I best solve this problem? I read about this ValueError in other questions, but the suggested solutions I tried do not work for my specific case.

The problem appears to be that Python does not understand that I refer to `data_dict_var_1` in `if data_dict == data_dict_var_1:`. I have to somehow more specify this line of code for both dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot check for dictionary equality. To solve you problem you can try the following:

```
var_1_list = []
var_2_list = []
var_dict = {'var_1_list': [],
           'var_2_list': []}
data_dicts = [data_dict_var_1, data_dict_var_2]
for i, data_dict in enumerate(data_dicts):
    all_rois = np.array([
        data_dict["interoception"],
        data_dict["exteroception"],
        data_dict["cognitive"]
        ])
    all_rois = np.hstack(all_rois)
    
    var_dict[f'var_{i+1}_list'].append(all_rois)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works (with the only slight change that the keys in var_dict need to start with 0 instead of 1). I spend more than two hours on this now and thought that there must be a way to check equality of dictionaries. Thanks again!

Comment: Ops. Just fixed it.